# Split string into array of character strings and count of splitted charcters in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, split

I need to split a String into an array of single character Strings and get count of splitted charcters .

Eg, splitting "character" would give the array `"c", "h", "a", "r",  "a", "c", "t", "e",  "r"`.

**EDIT**

Is it possible to get  count splitted string characters using inbuilt functions?

```
Array ( [c] => 2 [h] => 1 [a] => 2 [r] => 2 [t] => 1 [e] => 1 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

```
$array = str_split("cat");
```

---

Try [`count_chars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php):

```
<?php
$data = "Two Ts and one F.";

foreach (count_chars($data, 1) as $i => $val) {
   echo "There were $val instance(s) of \"" , chr($i) , "\" in the string.\n";
}
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
There were 4 instance(s) of " " in the string.
There were 1 instance(s) of "." in the string.
There were 1 instance(s) of "F" in the string.
There were 2 instance(s) of "T" in the string.
There were 1 instance(s) of "a" in the string.
There were 1 instance(s) of "d" in the string.
There were 1 instance(s) of "e" in the string.
There were 2 instance(s) of "n" in the string.
There were 2 instance(s) of "o" in the string.
There were 1 instance(s) of "s" in the string.
There were 1 instance(s) of "w" in the string.
```

Answer (score 4):

[**The Array `$array`**

```
$array = str_split('Cat');
```

**After splitting it with `str_split()` will look like this:**

```
ARRAY
{
   [0] = 'C'
   [1] = 'a'
   [2] = 't'
}
```

**ANSWER TO EDITED QUESTION**

Yes, you can use the function `count_chars()`

```
$str = "CHARACTERS";

$array = array();

foreach (count_chars($str, 1) as $i => $val) {
   array[] = array($str, $i);
}
```

**Will output the following:**

```
ARRAY
{
   [0] = ARRAY("C" => 2)
   [1] = ARRAY("H" => 1)
}
```

etc

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. When printing `$array`  `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => CHARACTERS
            [1] => 65
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => CHARACTERS
            [1] => 67
        )`....   etc

Answer (score 3):

use php function [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php),
example here:

```
$array = str_split("cat");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [str_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

i.e.

```
$array = str_split($str, 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use explode here the [doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
 /* A string that doesn't contain the delimiter will simply return a one-length array of the original string. */
 $input1 = "hello";
 $input2 = "hello,there";
 var_dump( explode( ',', $input1 ) );
 var_dump( explode( ',', $input2 ) );
```

Comment: Your syntax will give me as `Array ( [0] => cat )`. What I need is `Array ( [0] => c [1] => a [2] => t ) `